# SSL mismatch error using ISP-provided IP address but not VPN IP address

Tags: tls

I keep seeing error messages reporting issues with SSL (Chrome, IE, Mozilla) when clicking on links in the YAHOO homepage to stories from different YAHOO sites (screen, autos, movies, hsrd, etc.)

CHROME reports

> "A secure connection cannot be established because this site uses an
>   unsupported protocol. Error code: ERR SSL VERSION OR CIPHER MISMATCH."

MOZILLA reports:

> "Unable to Connect Securely. Firefox cannot guarantee the safety of
>   your data on autos.yahoo.com because it uses SSLv3, a broken security
>   protocol. Advanced info: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap".

The weird thing is that when I use a VPN (HotSpot Shield)... there is no error and I can access all these pages/sites without any problem or issue! Any ideas on why this happens? Is the SSL "mismatch" on my ISP's side, and if so, should I have any security concerns?

Comment: Occam's Razor would suggest that Firefox is warning you that autos.yahoo.com is susceptible to POODLE.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the SSL "mismatch" on my ISP's side, and if so, should I have any security concerns? Tks.

It can be at your ISP but it can also be a compromised router which redirects traffic. A VPN installed on your local machine might protect you in both cases.

If it is your ISP then other users of the ISP will probably be affected too, unless the ISP (or some hacker/agency there) targets especially you for some reason. So I think that a compromised router is more probable. Since routers are often insecure lots of them can easily be hacked with CSRF or similar attacks just by visiting some external web sites. The hack can change the DNS settings so that most traffic from then on is under control of the attacker. See for example the [compromise of millions of routers in brazil 2011/12](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2012/10/01/hacked-routers-brazil-vb2012/).

Answer (score -3):

Most likely it's because chrome and Firefox blocks some of "harmful sites" such as torrent sites. They are not actually harmful, but they just don't want you to use the torrents. Anyways, the reason why vpn allows you to access those sites is because the browser does not recognize them and therefore not block the sites.

Comment: This answer is completely incorrect in the scope of the question. The question asks in the scope of sites that *should not* be blocked (Yahoo).

Comment: This answer is completely incorrect.